# Send Data/Text from Web Application To Android

Tags: php, android, web

I am trying to communicate between a web application and an Android device in the following way:

- Log into my website with a unique id (eg. IMEI)
- Send data from android to the web application the user has logged into
- Send data from web browser to my application, e.g. with a simple html button

I know of the HttpUrlConnection class and other useful classes but I am unsure how to use them successfully.
Let's say I just need to send GPS coordinates from my application to the user logged into my website, and then click a button in my website to send a message to my app.

I'm looking for some recommendations of various technology/methods I should use to help me achieve this!

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you need webservices in your server. If your application do a GET request on your server, your server must return a response.. This response can be in form of an xml object. Here an example of get request http://imdbapi.org/?title=god+father&type=xml&plot=simple&episode=1&limit=1&yg=0&mt=none&lang=en-US&offset=&aka=simple&release=simple&business=0&tech=0

Comment: Thanks You , this Answer my Question , i will Find More Infos about Web Service

Comment: Thanks for edit David K :)

Comment: You are welcome Nikita!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SQL Server to manage the data on your desktop and create a web-service in .NET on Visual Studio.

Then connect to the web-service in your application and set/get data from the DB, using web-services.

*Links which might be useful :*

**How to make a web-service in .NET (does not include the implementation in Android) :** http://srikanthtechnologies.com/blog/dotnet/wsdaljava.aspx

**How to connect your service with Android :**

http://seesharpgears.blogspot.in/2010/11/basic-ksoap-android-tutorial.html

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/304302/Calling-Asp-Net-Webservice-ASMX-From-an-Android-Ap

http://adrianandroid.blogspot.in/2012/05/access-c-net-web-service-in.html

Comment: @Nikita : You are most welcome. Glad to be of help. All the best ahead! :)

Comment: Thanks again :) , i will look into your Solution , Another Question , can i use Google Cloud to Send Messgae to the Device Throught my Website to Achieve whats iam trying , using the Google Account on the Device ?

Comment: Well, yes! You can use Google Could Messaging (GCM) to send messages directly to the android device. Here are a few documents that would help you get started. http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/  http://developer.android.com/training/cloudsync/gcm.html   http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Comment: Thanks again :) , but as i can see , the server side is in Java ? how do i integrate it in my Website ?

Comment: I am not sure whether I get you, but I think what you are looking for is this https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/website-configuration.

Comment: iam not sure too , i mean , when Configuration is Done on the Android Side , for Google Cloud , from Where the User/Me can Send/Push a Message to the Device , from My Website ? or Cloud Web Page ? Anything to Configure ? , Sorry lol , i am not Experimented about this ...

Comment: Well, to be honest I haven't used Google Cloud integration on my website, so even I have no knowledge. I can search Google and tell you, but even you can do that for yourself. So my suggestion to you would be to start your development and keep on posting questions as you come across problems. Here on StackOverflow, it is much appreciated if your question contains the code that you have tried, instead of just theoretical questions, asking how to do this and how t do that. Choose a good tutorial on Google Cloud and follow it and post questions whenever you get stuck. *May the Droid be with you!*

Comment: i am sorry to comments again this Topic , but i still dont get it , i does not Understand the Mechanism/Logic , How from , for eg. an Html Button can i send Data/Text to the Phone Connected to the web Service ?

Comment: Hey @Nikita, nothing to be sorry about. It's perfectly okay to have problems, because what you are doing is pretty advanced stuff. But still it's pretty simple. When your HTML button is clicked, have a function to connect to your database to get the data that you want to send to the phone. Now, you can either have your phone poll for data, i.e. the phone will keep on sending a request to the server asking if there is any data to be sent. But this is not a great way to do things, as it consumes a lot of battery due to the polling. Istead use TCP push messages or GCM to send data to the phone.

Comment: And something that you may find of relevance : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology

Comment: Does GCM allow an User to Log In with his/her Gmail Account and Communicate himself with his/her Phone , like in the website i provided here ? Also , with GCM , what happen if an User use the Same Gmail account for 2 Devices with the same App Installed ?

Comment: @Nikita : You could use "Push" notification service to send the data from the server to the device. And I haven't played around GCM to be able to answer your questions on GCM properly. I could look around on google, but so can you. :P

Comment: yes :) , but i think i will use Database/Php Script , i am making some Test , the Mechanism i think to Use : Device Create a Tab in DB with an Unique ID , and [Message Name] , from the Html Page , an Test Button will write to that Unique ID , [Message Name] , Then the Phone will Poll every Minutes & Check the [Message Name] , Same in the Web Page , with a while(true) in the Html/Php Code , about the LogIn , i will use Imei Stored in DB , sorry if i can explain very well , do you understand it , it is ''Correct'' ?

Comment: Yes, I do get an idea of what you are trying to do. And yes, it is "correct". For the time being, go with the polling mechanism, but later integrate push service to make your application more optimized. Go ahead with your approach. Post questions here along with the code that you have tried. And if need be, feel free to hit me up on my FB/e-mail. :)

Comment: ok , ill keep you informed , thanks you very much for all your help :)

Comment: The one with the problem in connecting to the MySQL database ?